# How do i get HTML string with input values using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to create the HTML into a pdf on the server and need the HTML from the browser that has a `form` and other stuff in it. Doing `$el.html()` just gives an HTML string without `input` values in the form. How do i get the HTMl `string` with all the `input` values included?.

I do not want to append the clone on the browser, i am just interested in the HTML string with all input values to pass to the server.

Thanks!

Comment: jquery clone() maybe good for you

Comment: So you're trying to produce a PDF that is essentially a picture of the current state of the web page (including input values)? Or do you want to produce a PDF that actually has html code on it?

Comment: yes, i am trying to create a PDF that is the current state of the web page.

Comment: @user1108772 `clone` wouldn't store the input values.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work.  Simply run this before you call `.html()`:

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.attr("value", $this.val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GyrWY/1/

Note:  If you need to do this for other input types, they will need to be handled differently. For `textarea` you would set `.text($this.val())`, for checkboxes and radio buttons, you would need to set the `checked` attribute. `select` elements, you would have to set the `selected` attribute of the appropriate `option`.

Comment: You should use the `:input` selector to get all types of input, such as text areas, select menus, and checkboxes.

Comment: @Barmar But `<select value="abc">` isn't really valid.  And works even less for checkboxes.  Textarea would need to be handled differently as well.

Comment: You just beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will do it:

```
$("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
$("textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).val());
});
$("select option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
    }
});
$("checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

This sets the appropriate DOM attributes for all types of inputs to match their current state. I hope I didn't miss any.

You might want to make a clone of the entire DOM and operate on it. The above code will affect what happens if the user presses the Reset button of the forms, the current state will be considered the default.

Comment: Edited my answer to handle types of input that don't use the `value` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar -  Hi, it is not working for ion-checkbox, how to do the same for it

Comment: @surendher I don't know what ion-checkbox is.

Comment: @Barmar - Thats ok, i have found a solution for it. Thanks